# fetch the field data without post

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm trying to get the field data from form textarea so i can store it when a user filling the textarea if he reload page or open an other page in same tab and come back to write data his previous work will be there
My code is

```
session_start();
     $_SESSION['textarea-133'] = $_POST["textarea-133"];
     ?>
     <script>

    var a="<php echo $_SESSION['textarea-133']";
    document.getElementById("business_a6").value =a ;
     </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `window.sessionStorage` to save a variable and check if it's there each time the page is loaded.

```
window.onload = function(){
    var userText = sessionStorage.getItem('the_user_text');
    if( userText ){
        document.getElementById('the-text-area').innerHTML = userText;
    }
};
```

It's up to you if you want to re-save the variable with each `keypress` or maybe after a `setInterval`

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  var newText = document.getElementById('the-text-area');
  sessionStorage.setItem('the_user_text', newText);
});
```

Comment: @HuzailSpy Glad I could help. `localStorage` is the whole browser, `sessionStorage` is for the specific tab.